# MinGW-W64: gdb requires python?

Tags: gdb, mingw-w64

I'm working on Windows 11, and I've installed MinGW-W64 as seen below. I've tried to run GDB (which I believe it has), but it has some error message saying something about Python. I do have Python as well.

```
me@myLaptop MINGW64 ~
$ gcc --version
gcc.exe (MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-mcf-seh, built by Brecht Sanders) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


me@myLaptop MINGW64 ~
$ python --version
Python 3.12.0
```

gdb error:

```
me@myLaptop MINGW64 ~
$ gdb --version
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'C:\mingw64\bin\libpython3.9.dll'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = 'C:/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 'R:/winlibs64ucrt_stage/inst_cpython-mingw-3.9.7/share/python'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'R:/winlibs64ucrt_stage/inst_cpython-mingw-3.9.7/share/python'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = 'C:/mingw64/bin/gdb.exe'
  sys.prefix = 'R:/winlibs64ucrt_stage/inst_cpython-mingw-3.9.7/share/python'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'R:/winlibs64ucrt_stage/inst_cpython-mingw-3.9.7/share/python'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\mingw64\\lib\\python3.9',
    'R:/winlibs64ucrt_stage/inst_cpython-mingw-3.9.7/share/python/lib/python39.zip',
    'R:/winlibs64ucrt_stage/inst_cpython-mingw-3.9.7/share/python/lib/python3.9',
    'R:/winlibs64ucrt_stage/inst_cpython-mingw-3.9.7/share/python/lib/lib-dynload',
    '',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00006484 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
```

Does gdb just not work on Windows?

I've reinstalled python and looked up what PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH were (but they don't seem to be relevant).

Comment: gdb works on Windows just fine. You have installed python 3.12.0, but the gdb you have is looking for 3.9.7. Didn't come this gdb with a matching python? Or at least some instructions where you can get it?